# Changing font tag with PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I have a PDF which embeds a TrueType font called UnicodeDoc. Within the PDF I can see the following:

```
/BaseFont /IKOTCH+UnicodeDoc
```

Is it possible using PDFBox to change the tag value `IKOTCH` and if so how? I know that this value may be different for other documents. However I just need acces to this tag.

Comment: *Is it possible using PDFBox to change the tag value* - most likely it is because PDFBox allows a low-level access to the PDF objects. That been said, though, remember that if there is an associated **FontDescriptor**. the **FontName** entry therein must likewise be adapted.

Comment: Ok, now I know that it is possible. I should have been asking for a code snippet :-)